# Yii2 share session between 2 apps

Tags: php, session, yii2

Currently, my application have the following structure:

- frontend
- backend (user authenticated)
- client (user authenticated)

**What I'm trying to do is to pass a flash message from the client to the frontend**.

In the client app I simple set the flash:

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('successMessage', 'My success message!');
```

And in the frontend:

```
Yii::$app->session->getFlash('successMessage');
```

But the above obviously is not working.

I've already tried to set equal session id in the config/main.php of both apps, but there seems to be no different:

```
'components' => [
    'session' => [
        'name' => '_mySharedSessionId',
        'savePath' => __DIR__ . '/../runtime',  
    ],
    ...
]
```

Any ideas where I'm wrong?

**UPDATE**
The problem maybe came from that I have set 4 different vhosts for each app: local-frontend, local-backend, local-client. If I revert it to the default, all seems to work fine. So my question now is:
Is there an universal way to share a session between the above vhosts so that when the site is uploaded for production it will work also there (probably the urls on production will be something like www.mysite.com, www.client.mysite.com, www.admin.mysite.com)?

Comment: How many domains are you using? As I am not sure you can share the session if you are running on different domains.

Comment: Check that the session cookie between your applications is matching.

Comment: Actually, the problems is because for each app I have set different vhosts:
local-frontend, local-backend, local-client. If switch back to the default localhost all seems to work fine. I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share the session from one application to another without hindering the domain configuration of the app, then you should try memcache!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: If you have multiple application, you can use memcache[d]. Memcached provides a session handler by using which you can simply use sessions from one application to another.
You can refer to the below link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-php-sessions-on-multiple-memcached-servers-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Note that storing sessions in Memcache can be problematic. If Memcache is stopped (for whatever reason) you will loose all data you have in it. You may want to consider storing your sessions in a database and also have them in Memcache to speedup the process. So that you can use these sessions two whatever application you want to.

Answer (score -1):

Add below code in your `controller` file

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('delete', "Member Deleted Successfully.......");
```

And add below code in your `view` or `index` file

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('delete')): ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
      <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" type="button">×</button>
      <h4><i class="icon fa fa-check"></i>Deleted!</h4>
      <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('delete') ?>
   </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in your php configuration and not specific to Yii2. You should explicitly set [session.cookie_domain](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain) parameter in php.ini:

```
session.cookie_domain = ".example.com"
```

Alternatively, you can do that in php using `ini_set` (for example, in your `web/index.php`):

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com' );
```

By default, that variable restricts cookies to current domain, but setting it to `.example.com` (notice the dot prefix) will allow to use the same cookie for example.com, www.example.com, foo.example.com, bar.example.com, but *not* example.org.

Specifically for your local installation, change vhosts to `frontend.local`, `backend.local`, and `client.local`, and set `cookie_domain` to `.local`.

Comment: As I wrote in the updated part of the question, the problem came from the vhosts format. Now I am looking for a universal sharing session method that will not bother with the domain configuration on production. (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: But that's the whole idea - you configure php to treat cookies from different domains as if they came from one domain. That and storing cookies in a db should solve your problem.