# How to allow auto login into Yii1 app once authenticated from Yii2 App

Tags: php, session, yii, yii2, yii1.x

I am creating a main hub using Yii2 as a base, my goal is to ask users to login into the Yii2 app and store a session into a certain folder. Then inside the Yii2 app there will be links into older Yii1 apps that use stored session in a folder.

I have successfully made both apps start to store sessions into a specific folder in C://sessions but to no avail i couldn't get the Yii1 app to recognize the session that the Yii2 app has created.

My question is how do i allow auto login into the Yii1 app after the user has logged into the Yii2 app?

The configs below have not been successful as i cant seem to get the Yii1 app to recognize the session created by the Yii2 app. Is it even possible for them to share the same session?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Yii2 - web.php**

```php
'components' => [
        'session'=>[
            'class'=>'yii\web\Session',
            'savePath'=>"C:\sessions",  //change session path
            'timeout' => 600,
            'cookieParams'=>[
                'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                'expire' => 600
            ],
        ],
```

**Yii1 - main.php**

```php
'components'=>array(
        'session'=>array(
            'class'=>'CHttpSession',
            'savePath'=>"C:\sessions",  //change session path
            'cookieMode'=>'allow',
            'timeout' => 600,
            'cookieParams'=>array(
                'domain' => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                'expire' => 600
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: Please, look [here](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/sharing-session-between-applications/48184) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570950/yii2-share-session-between-2-apps). I know it is not the same case, but you might see something that will work. Please, keep me posted on the resolution. If nothing of these works, you can always just use plain old fashion php session sharing, outside of the framework.

Comment: Yii 1 and Yii 2 have different session data structure - it is highly unlikely that using the same session file will work for these 2 different implementations. You should probably create your own implementation for Yii 1 which will be compatible with data from Yii 2 session.